# Dependent removed from Health Insurance Coverage

Tags: united-states

My newborn has been removed from Health insurance coverage after *failing to upload documents* to verify the qualifying life status event.

There were 2 documents uploaded, one which successfully uploaded.

After some experimenting I found that the upload portal has a document size limit of 20MB for in the document portal. However, it looks like there are 2 different responses to trying to upload large documents. If the document is large but not too large (greater 20MB and less than 50MB) the portal says there is an error uploading the document. When uploading my document (60MB) the window displays.

*The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large.*

So my second document failed to upload, and I didn't realize until the enrollment window had ended.

There was no notice that my the documents were incomplete and I discovered that my son was not covered the same way it seems everyone discovers they no longer have coverage at the doctors office.

Does something like this qualify me for another special enrollment period, or am I just out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to ask whomever is the administrator for your plan, and hope that they will make an exception. [There is no special enrollment period](https://www.healthcare.gov/coverage-outside-open-enrollment/special-enrollment-period/) for "the upload tool didn't work" but many plan administrators who see that you had experienced a confusing issue during enrollment will make an exception.

If your plan administrator won't make an exception, you can always raise the case to whatever entity oversees health insurance in your state (i.e. the department of labor or department of finance).

Finally, if you find yourself completely and utterly without any luck trying to get your son added to your existing insurance, you may want to pursue other low-cost options for insruance. Many states have no- or low-cost options for insuring children, i.e. [CHIP](https://www.healthcare.gov/medicaid-chip/childrens-health-insurance-program/).

And I know this is not helpful, because it's after the fact, but any time I add or change enrollment, I ask for an updated ID card (if dependent names are printed on the cards) and/or check enrollment directly with the actual insurer via phone, to verify that everything went through OK.